# How to match one or more non-slash characters

Tags: linux, regex

I am given a relative path that descends n levels deep and want to produce
the "reverse" path that ascends the same number of levels.  I want to
produce the same number of levels with or without a trailing space.
For example:

```
dir/subdir/subsubdir  should produce ../../..
dir/subdir/subsubdir/ should produce ../../../
```

Why does a plus operator fail to find a match?  Doesn't this mean one or
more non-slash characters?

```
$ echo dir/subdir/subsubdir | sed 's|[^/]+|..|g'
dir/subdir/subsubdir
```

whereas a single character match followed by a star match works:

```
$ echo dir/subdir/subsubdir | sed 's|[^/][^/]*|..|g'
../../..
```

even with a trailing slash:

```
$ echo dir/subdir/subsubdir/ | sed 's|[^/][^/]*|..|g'
../../../
```

FWIW, a star (*) will work in place of the plus (+):

```
$ echo dir/subdir/subsubdir | sed 's|[^/]*|..|g'
../../..
```

but then a trailing slash won't do because it adds another level:

```
$ echo dir/subdir/subsubdir/ | sed 's|[^/]*|..|g'
../../../../..
```

Comment: What operating system? GNU/Linux or a BSD flavor (like OS X)?

Comment: I'm using GNU bash on Ubuntu:

$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

In 'man sed' I see "-r use extended regular expressions"
It also says "REGULAR EXPRESSIONS POSIX.2" -- is that the flavor?
Where would I find that \+ is required for "one or more"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are many flavors of regex syntax out there, each with its own slight (or sometimes not-so-slight) variations. Assuming you are using GNU sed, either of these options would work:

```
$ echo dir/subdir/subsubdir | sed 's|[^/]\+|..|g'
../../..
$ echo dir/subdir/subsubdir | sed -r 's|[^/]+|..|g'
../../..
```

In general, you'll want to check the man page of whatever tool you're using to see what flavor it uses.